# How to get Windows System information for CPU, memory (etc) in C++

Tags: c++, windows, operating-system

On Windows 10, I can right click on the start menu, select "System" and be presented with a dialog of system information, including "Device Specifications" that tells me things like:

- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9700 CPU @ 3.00GHz   3.00GHz
- Installed Ram: 16.0GB

Where can one obtain this information in a form suitable to write to an application log? I want to be able to read back through our logs and detect gross hardware changes (e.g. PC failure leading to a new/different PC running our application). Our application is deployed on a mix of Win 8 and Win 10 systems.

I think the answer is [WMI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-start-page). But WMI appears to be a (complex, dense, intimidating) forest, and I'm only interested in one or two trees - the minimum human-readable text to (roughly) characterise the computer system my application is running on.

Is there anything simpler than WMI that will provide this information? If not, since none of the MS [WMI C++ examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-c---application-examples) give any example output (leading me to question if WMI is what I want...), can someone suggest a straightforward starting point or example for obtaining those two system details as strings?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/850812/1553090

Comment: You can read from the registry as I have shown (for an ARM system, but works for any) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60589197/10871073).